# How to type following object/type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following:

a user type which is:

```
export type User = {
  id: string | null;
  email: string | null;
  firstName: string | null;
  lastName: string | null;
  verified: boolean | null;
};
```

and the following state:

```
let initialState: UserSliceState = {
  user: {
    id: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    email: null,
    verified: null,
  },
  error: null,
  isLoading: false,
};
```

and i wanna type it but i don't know how to, i tried this:

```
type UserSliceState = {
  user: {
    [field: keyof User]: User;
  };
  error: string | null;
  isLoading: boolean;
};
```

but it gives me an error on `[field: keyof User]` and i don't know if what i did is valid:
it says `An index signature parameter can't be a union type, consider using a mapped object instead`

any ideeas? thanks

Comment: user: User?????

Comment: Why don't you just say `user: User;' in UserSliceType?

Comment: This: `[field: keyof User]: User` seems wrong. Instead try `[field: keyof User]: string | null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add your user type to the `UserSliceState`

```
type UserSliceState = {
  user: User;
  error: string | null;
  isLoading: boolean;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the first thing i tried but it threw some error due to a function that wasn't complete above.